# Bind Silverlight to a database?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I heard that Mango will have a local database available. I'm a bit of a novice regarding this whole thing

Is it possible to use Silverlight data binding to connect to a database and automatically receive updates etc or is it something that takes a bit more work? Perhaps it is necessary to add helper functions that return lists from the database and you bind to those internal lists instead of directly to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a msdn tutorial on [how to build a MVVM application using a local database for windows phone 7 mango](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286405.aspx).

You may also take a look at [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).